# Getting invalid syntax of customer id while doing paytm

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway, paytm

I am using the Paytm payment gateway in my laravel project. but for this user, I get this error every time I start to make a paymentt.

```
      'order' => $order_ID,
      'user' => Auth::user()->name,
      'mobile_number' => Auth::user()->mob_no,
      'email' => Auth::user()->email,
      'amount' => $wallet_package->wallet_amt_to_be_paid,
```

[image: paytm error]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the cus_ID:"CUST_01". It will

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @gprakash sir, where should I add **CUST_01** ??

Comment: For android app -> If user login, you can get info from  userinfo API.
For Api -> based on signin user token, you can get and set.
For ex:- I have login into abc app.Now backend teams will know the users details.
based on the token, all details get.

Comment: @swapnil mane
 now working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "CUST_ID"=>"any Unique cust ID".

In addition, I will recommend to use Paytm JsCheckout Solution.
For Documentation: Open "paytm developer docs jsCheckout".
The Sample code for Laravel JsCheckout integration is available on GitHub.
github.com/paytm/paytm-laravel-js-checkout

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).